# How to do tagging in a feature mercurial branch using teamcity build

Tags: mercurial, tags, label, teamcity

I am trying to tag a mercurial feature branch using teamcity. But it is doing nothing. I am following the following link and it works well with svn repository:-

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Labeling

Following are my settings in teamcity:-

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Please guide.
Thanks